# How do I display a "please wait" message during a long operation in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

When a page is first called, I'd like to be display a "please wait" message while they are waiting for the page to load.  However in the example below the page doesn't render until **someLongProcess** completes.

I suspect I need to use something like AJAX to display the initial "please wait" message then start my initial processing.  Any suggestions?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Call SetupGUI() 'user doesnt see this setup until page is rendered.
        Call someLongProcess()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets me begin by describing whats wrong with you approach before I explain, how can you accomplish your task

When you wrote this piece of code, you assumed that that the client and server are somehow connected and can talk to each other when ever they want. Sadly that is not the case. HTTP is a stateless protocol. You might be wondering, what does a stateless protocol means?

Lets suppose the server is James and he has telephone line, which does not have a Caller ID. He gets thousand of call every day from different clients asking a question. Now James is very knowlegable and can answer those questions quickly but once he discounts from the client, he can not call them back (Remember no caller ID, means that James cant call back the client).

This all OK, when you have short question to ask but If you have question which require's James to think about the answer, you either need to wait on the line, while James thinks, or you want James to call you back.

In order to wait on the phone you would need to increase the ASP.Net executionTimeOut value in the webconfig. The default value is 110 seconds and while you wait for the answer, you can display a loading / progress spinner using the code below

```
<div id="preloader" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                    <img src="../Images/loading.gif" alt="" style="display: block;" />
                </div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function HidePreloader() {
        if (document.getElementById('preloader') != null) {
            document.getElementById('preloader').style.visibility = 'hidden';

        }
    }
</script>
```

Just call the function HidePreloader on button / link click.

This is all hunky dory but remember James is a old guy and he can only listen to 10 calls simultaneously. If 10 people are already taking to James then, the he wont be able to answer the 11th call. This is not good, what we want is a way for James to call us back. We want to give James a caller ID. Sadly Caller ID's will not be available until Windows 8 server and only to those clients (browsers) which have support for [websockets](http://websocket.org/).

So what else can we do, How can we solve this problem, Oh wait, what if we give James our name and tell him, I will call back in 5 minutes to see if you have figured out the answer. This is known as polling. Basically you ask the server to complete a long running task and the server gives you token. Every few minutes or seconds, you ask the server, this is my token, is my task complete. If the task is complete, you populate the page with the new data. This is traditionally accomplished using Javascript and Web services. You can also look at this framework [SignalIR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) which provides methods to accomplish this sort of thing.

Hopefully, this mental model will help you better understand the stateless nature of HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

Your going to what to look at creating an asynchronous page for this requirement.  There is a nice article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx that explains the process very well.  It's an older article so take that for what it's worth.  Also, take a look at the PageAsyncTask class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx.

The links above should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned AJAX.  If you want to do it in JavaScript, maybe something like this: http://pure-essence.net/2010/01/29/jqueryui-dialog-as-loading-screen-replace-blockui/